# How to change value if error occurs in for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, error-handling

I have a loop that reads HTML table data from ~ 440 web pages.  The code on each page is not exactly the same, so sometimes I need table node 1 and sometime I need node 2.  Right now I've just been setting the node number manually in a list and feeding it into the loop. My problem is that the page nodes have started changing and updating the node # list is getting to be a hassle.

If the loop encounters the wrong node # (ie: 1 instead of 2, or reverse) it gives an error and shuts down.  Is there a way to have the loop replace the erroneous node number to the correct one if it encounters an error, and then keep running the loop as if nothing happened?

Here's the readHTML portion of the code in my loop with an example url:

```
url <- "http://espn.go.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/2991280/year/2013/"

html.page <- htmlParse(url)

tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html.page, "//table")

x <- as.numeric(Players$Nodes[s])

tbl = readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[x]], colClasses = c("character"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here's the error I get when the node # is wrong:

> "Error in readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[x]], colClasses = c("character"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : error in evaluating the argument 'doc' in selecting a method for function 'readHTMLTable': Error in tableNodes[[x]] : subscript out of bounds"

Example code:

---

```
A <- c("dog", "cat")

Nodes <- as.data.frame(1:1) 

#)Nodes <- as.data.frame(1:2) <-- This works without errors

colnames(Nodes)[1] <- "Col1"

Nodes2 <- 2

url <-c("http://espn.go.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/6639/year/2013/","http://espn.go.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/6630/year/2013/")

for (i in 1:length(A))  
{ 


html.page <- htmlParse(url[i])

tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html.page, "//table")

x <- as.numeric(Nodes$Col1[i])

df = readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[x]], colClasses = c("character"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#tryCatch(df) here.....no clue


assign(paste0("", A[i]), df)
}
```

Comment: You can use `tryCatch` for that. See `?tryCatch` and this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647961/using-trycatch-in-the-integral-and-mapply

Comment: I've been trying out tryCatch, but so far I'm not getting anywhere. I think that's definitely the way to go, I just haven't been able to figure out the code yet.

Comment: Then post your code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the trycatch code is over my head.  The help and examples I've found are not leading me anywhere.

Comment: I've added a simplified version of my loop that you can run.  Maybe if someone could simply explain where to start with the trycatch code I could go from there. I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `subscript out of bounds` error msg, then you should try to with a lower `x` for sure. General demo with `tryCatch` based on the demo code you posted in the original question (although I have replaced `x` with `2` as I have no idea what is `Players` and `s`):

```
> msg <- tryCatch(readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[2]], colClasses = c("character"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE), error = function(e)e)
> str(msg)
List of 2
 $ message: chr "error in evaluating the argument 'doc' in selecting a method for function 'readHTMLTable': Error in tableNodes[[2]] : subscript"| __truncated__
 $ call   : language readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[2]], colClasses = c("character"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
> msg$message
[1] "error in evaluating the argument 'doc' in selecting a method for function 'readHTMLTable': Error in tableNodes[[2]] : subscript out of bounds\n"
> grepl('subscript out of bounds', msg$message)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @DerekPierson: When you posted that comment you _should_ have clicked the checkmark outline and you _should_ have clicked the up-arrow. (I know you didn't because I was the first to do so.)

Comment: @DWin Could you explain your comment further?  Do what where?

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help, I've got the tryCatch code working now.

Comment: SO is a reputation driven facility. Read the root to the help page and http://stackoverflow.com/about . If you don't participate in recognizing effective answers, it's your reputation that will suffer.